# Match values of two dictionaries and update list inside one of the dictionaries with matching key value pair

Tags: python-3.x

Hello have tried to figure this out for some time without much luck so any help is greatly appreciated.

Trying to match the titles of the aa list of dictionaries to the titled of the bb list of dictionaries and update the aa list of dictionaries to a key value combination

```
aa = [{'link': 'www.home.com', 'title': ['one', 'two', 'three']}, {'link': 'www.away.com', 'title':['two', 'three']}]

bb = [{'id': 1, 'title' :'one'},{'id': 2, 'title': 'two'}, {'id': 3, 'title': 'three'}]


result = [{'link':'www.home.com', 'title':[{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}]}, {'link': 'www.away.com', 'title':[{'two': 2, 'three': 3}]}
```

]

Comment: both of the solutions worked below thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is:

```
result = [{'link': 'www.home.com', 'title': [{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}]}, {'link': 'www.away.com', 'title': [{'two': 2, 'three': 3}]}]
```

Refer my code as below:

```
from copy import deepcopy

aa = [{'link': 'www.home.com', 'title': ['one', 'two', 'three']}, {'link': 'www.away.com', 'title':['two', 'three']}]
bb = [{'id': 1, 'title' :'one'},{'id': 2, 'title': 'two'}, {'id': 3, 'title': 'three'}]

titleids = {}
for b in bb:
    titleids[b['title']] = b['id']

result = deepcopy(aa)
for a in result:
    a['title'] = [{title:titleids[title] for title in a['title']}]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b1={k["title"]:k["id"] for k in bb}
```

just to solve this example you will do:

```
[ {'link':l['link'],'title':{i:b1[i] for i in l["title"]}} for l in aa]

[{'link': 'www.home.com', 'title': {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}}, {'link': 'www.away.com', 'title': {'two': 2, 'three': 3}}]
```

Although if you had many other keys you will do:

```
[{i:({k:b1[k] for k in j} if i is 'title' else j) for i,j in l.items()} for l in aa]

[{'link': 'www.home.com', 'title': {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}}, {'link': 'www.away.com', 'title': {'two': 2, 'three': 3}}]
```